# JPA annotation DiscriminatorColumn - how to set index

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Is it possible using JPA or even Hibernate to set index of discriminator column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using the Hibernate Table annotation:

```
@Table(appliesTo="tableName", 
       indexes = {@Index(name="index1", columnNames={"the_discriminator_column"})})
```

Answer (score 0):

It's best not to create indexes on your discriminator columns.

Discriminator columns naturally have a very low number of distinct values; one per each concrete entity class which is derived from the base entity class.

Hence, their indexes are going to be low-cardinality indexes: small amount of index tree nodes, each holding large amounts of record ID references.

As a result, the execution planner is very likely going to skip scanning this index, even at the cost of performing a full table scan.

See Vuong Hong An's article: [Can an index be slower than a full table scan?](https://blog.anvuong.xyz/low-cardinality-index-performance/)